# Getting the XmlNode value for each xml node

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

I am using the below xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore xmlns="urn:newbooks-schema">  
  <book>
    <title>Books</title>
    <price>20.00</price>
  <attribute>
      <fieldName>Books</fieldName>
      <attributeStyle>ValueSet</attributeStyle>
      <valueset>
        <id>Part 1</id>
        <values>
          <displayName>Lord of the Rings</displayName>
        </values>
      </valueset>
    </attribute>
  </book>  
  
  <book>
    <title>Books</title>
    <price>20.00</price>
    <attribute>
      <fieldName>Books</fieldName>
      <valueset>
        <id>Part 1</id>
        <values>
          <displayName>Harry Potter</displayName>
        </values>
      </valueset>
    </attribute>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I am trying to get each node "book" in an XMLNodeList and I am looping the nodes to get the individual data of the node "values". I have used the below code and tried to achieve it But the valuenodes is always returning both the values nodes i.e., Lord of the Rings and the Harry Potter together and not in each loop. I want to achieve it one by one in a loop and not all together.

```
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(text);
        var root = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "urn:newbooks-schema");

        XmlNodeList criterion = root.SelectNodes("bk:book[bk:title='Books']", nsmgr);

        foreach (XmlNode criterionNode in criterion)
        {
            XmlNode xml = criterionNode.SelectSingleNode("//bk:valueset", nsmgr);
            var valuesNodeExpression = "//bk:valueset/bk:values[../../bk:fieldName='Books']";
            XmlNodeList valueNodes = criterionNode.SelectNodes(valuesNodeExpression, nsmgr);
        }
```

Comment: Please tag a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly refactored the code, giving more telling names to the variables.

```
// Here the previous code is unchanged.

var books = root.SelectNodes("bk:book[bk:title='Books']", nsmgr);
Console.WriteLine(books.Count);

foreach (XmlNode book in books)
{
    var valueset = book.SelectSingleNode(".//bk:valueset", nsmgr);
    var id = valueset.SelectSingleNode("./bk:id", nsmgr).InnerText;
    var displayName = valueset.SelectSingleNode(".//bk:displayName", nsmgr).InnerText;

    Console.WriteLine(id);
    Console.WriteLine(displayName);
}
```